# Partitioning Postgres Read in Spark

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark

I am trying to query huge data from postgres using SparkSQl. I do see 100 partionion on the query stage , however , there is only one query running and only one executer executing.

Code :

```
df = sqlcontext.read.format('jdbc').options(url=params['url']
                                            ,driver=params["driver"]
                                            ,dbtable=tableName
                                            ,user=params['user']
                                            ,password=params['password']
                                            ,numPartitions=numberOfPartitions
                                            ,partitionColumn=partitionC
                                            ,lowerBound=lowerB
                                            ,upperBound=upperB).load()
```

The `partitionC` is of type date, I even tried a similar thing on a numeric column. I also made sure that the data is well balanced.

[image]

[image]

How to make spark execute multiple queries to postgres?

already referred to
[SparkSQL PostgresQL Dataframe partitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31341790/sparksql-postgresql-dataframe-partitions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Truns out you need to have a Index on the column in Database on which you are partitioning the data.

So the following implemnetation is quite valid.

```
df = sqlcontext.read.format('jdbc').options(url=params['url']
                                            ,driver=params["driver"]
                                            ,dbtable=tableName
                                            ,user=params['user']
                                            ,password=params['password']
                                            ,numPartitions=numberOfPartitions
                                            ,partitionColumn=partitionC
                                            ,lowerBound=lowerB
                                            ,upperBound=upperB).load()
```

The `partitionC` is of type `numeric` as a timestamp, with index in the databse

Answer (score 0):

Please provide numeric column as the partition column.

Provide the lower value and the upper value of the numeric column.

Please keep number of partions as 10. If there are to many database might clog.

Comment: I have tried it with numeric column, but no luck. Also the lower value and the upper value are numeric respectively when i tried it with numeric column

Comment: Low and upper bound are min and max of the numeric column

Comment: And see how many executors are processing in the executor tab. Also please cache and do count rather than show on data frame.

Comment: @NehaJirafe You still have the issue.